# Installing a different Nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 an [ASUS TUF A15](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-A15/specifications/) with an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660TI GPU. According to [NVIDIA](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/146629/en-us), the driver version for this GPU is 430. When I first installed Ubuntu, I installed 440. I'm now trying to correct that and install 430.

I ran `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-430`, and then did a reboot. When I examined `nvidia-smi`, though, it still showed the 440:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.100      Driver Version: 440.100      CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 166...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   55C    P0     9W /  N/A |      0MiB /  5944MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

What is the appropriate way of updating this driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu it doesn't matter what the NVIDIA website says. It matters what the results of `ubuntu-drivers devices` are. Ubuntu is bundled with a tool named ubuntu-drivers which detects and installs proprietary graphics driver packages. It detects proprietary graphics driver packages with `ubuntu-drivers devices`. The `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` command replaces all the unnecessary guesswork by automatically installing the correct proprietary graphics driver packages if there aren't any proprietary graphics packages currently installed.